# Convert all date/datetime elements to local timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs

how to  convert all elements with date/datetime string to display in users local timezone in javascript(jquery, moment or anything). all datetime text with classname to localtime zone using `jquery` or `moment.js` or any `javascript` methods.

In https://momentjs.com/timezone/ there is a timezone method. but how can we do it in one method

Comment: Please elaborate your question and please share us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is make sure that the server returns datetime in ISO 8601-format per [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

Then you can use that datetime or get all elements with appropriate class associated with it using javascript or jquery.

**Javascript for converting UTC DateTime to local user's DateTime**

```
var utcDateTime = '2019-05-15T08:33:48.000Z';  // ISO-8601 formatted date returned from server
var localDateTime = new Date(utcDateTime);
```

The localDateTime will be in the right local time which in my case would be three hours later (GR time).

**jQuery to change val of said elements**

```
$('.yourDateclass').each(function() {
    $(this).val(localDateTime);
});
```